# How to get data from a CrossPage Post in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, post

I'm having a problem with getting data from crosspage form posts in ASP.NET.

Basic layout of my pages is like this:
.aspx using the Masterpage "Default.master".
In the "Default.master.cs" I check if Session["user_IsLoggedIn"] exists and is true.
If it is I load an WebUserControl named "ShowLoginInformationControl.ascx".
If not I load "ShowLoginFormControl.ascx".

As you can guess the first shows some login information, the latter shows a quicklogin form and a register button:

```
<asp:TextBox Id="QuickloginUserName" RunAt="server" />
<asp:TextBox Id="QuickloginPassword" TextMode="Password" RunAt="server" />
<asp:Button ID="LoginSubmit" CssClass="LoginSubmit" meta:resourcekey="Login_LoginSubmit" PostBackUrl="~/Login.aspx" runat="server" />
```

The form targets to "Login.aspx". There is another login form on that page, so user can shoose to use the quicklogin or navigate to the login page.

The problem is: 
I'm not able to get the form data from the quicklogin form.

The code on Login.aspx.cs looks like this:

```
if( Page.IsPostBack )
{
    // POST from this page
    userName = UserName.Text;
    password = Password.Text;
}
else if( PreviousPage != null && PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack )
{
    // POST from user control
    TextBox userNamePreviousPageTextBox = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("QuickloginUserName");
    TextBox passwordPreviousPageTextBox = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("QuickloginPassword");

    userName = userNamePreviousPageTextBox.Text;
    password = passwordPreviousPageTextBox.Text;
}
```

Getting data from the page itself works well, getting data from the previous page.. not. :(

When using the quicklogin Im getting a NullReferenceError, cause FindControl returns null.

**How do I get the data from those two input fields?**

P.S.
I'm not using ASP.NET membership, which may be a mistake, but for now I don't have the time to "learn" to use it. If (even with help) I wont get it to work Ill have to replace the quicklogin with a hyperlink to the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're much better off creating public properties for the values you're trying to retrieve. FindControl is fragile at the best of times, but even more so in retrieving previous page values.

Try this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx

Scroll down to '**Getting Public Property Values from the Source Page**'

**Edit**

You could also create a base class for the master page, and then cast the PreviousPage's master page to that class. Then you'd have access to the properties of the master page, strongly typed. There are some good examples on complex master pages here: http://odetocode.com/code/450.aspx

Comment: I tried that before, but the problem is, that the **PreviousPageType** may only contain one sourcepage. The login-form however is implemented in the master page, so the form may be submitted from every page on the website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go one more layer down to use findcontrol to get your text boxes. You first need to find the Login control. You can also make it much easier on yourself and have two properties, UserName and Password that only have get accessors that return the respective values of the text boxes.

```
ShowLoginFormControl loginControl = (ShowLoginFormControl)PreviousPage.FindControl("previousPageLoginControlName");
```

or you can still use findcontrol on the loginControl to find your UserName and Password Text boxes

Comment: Hmm, I think I dont fully understand the way it works. Following your advice I tried the following: **TextBox userNamePreviousPageTextBox = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("ShowLoginFormControl").FindControl("QuickloginUserName");** to first find the LoginFormControl. But it still returns **null**. I load the control in the Default.master.cs by doing the following: if( blabla) { _showControl = (ShowLoginFormControl)LoadControl( "~/Shared/WebUserControls/ShowLoginFormControl.ascx" ); } else { blabla } then **PH_Login.Controls.Add( _showControl );**